# jQuery UI autocomplete select event not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm having quite a bit of trouble getting select or the focus functions to respond. I can't even kill the results in the select once I expand the results. I read a lot about certain versions of jQuery UI conflicting with the main jQuery library but pretty much any combination doesn't seem to work. Worse, it's not throwing any errors in console. Everything below select/focus seem to work fine. I am appending some HTML to each item and in my application I am styling them different based on a class. I would like to use select to append some extra HTML using ui.item.label below the input itself (like a tagging system). I am just using the alert to troubleshoot in the meantime.

Here is a fiddle that has my half-working code.

http://jsfiddle.net/c3UM5/

```
$(function () {

var availableItems = [{
    value: "recent",
    label: "Recent",
    classN: "heading"
}, {
    value: "all",
    label: "All",
    classN: "all"
}, {
    value: "lorem",
    label: "Lorem",
    classN: "lorem"
}, ];

$(".post-to").autocomplete({
    source: availableItems,
    minLength: 0,
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        $('.post-to').val(ui.item.label);
        alert(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        alert(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    }
}).on("focus", function () {
    $(this).autocomplete("search", '');
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<span class='" + item.classN + "'></span><span>" + item.label + "</span>")
        .appendTo(ul);
  };

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just have some minor issue (with quite huge consequences)

In your `_renderItem` function which you overwrite you try to append the elements with `<span>` tags but you need to define them as `<a>` tags.

See my <kbd>[**updated jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/c3UM5/1/)</kbd> of your code.

I just changed this:

```
$(".post-to").autocomplete()
    .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            //instead of <span> use <a>
            .append("<a class='" + item.classN + "'></a><a>" + item.label + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Alerts work fine now!

I guess this "limitation" is made due to style the appended elements properly. If you look at the styles that get applied they are defined for `<a>`tags. Like

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a
.ui-widget-content a
```

Comment: Yup! That's pretty bizarre. Such a small issue but now the rendered HTML is completely different. That did it.